# MxGraph - Remove node css style with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, mxgraph

I want to remove a CSS style from a mxgraph cell.
I have added the style like this:

```
let style = node.style;
style = mxUtils.setStyle(style, 'strokeColor', color);
self.graph.model.setStyle(node, style);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the style to `null` or `undefined`. The `mxUtils.setStyle` function takes care of removing the style from the style string:

```
let style = node.style;
style = mxUtils.setStyle(style, 'strokeColor', null); // <<<<<
self.graph.model.setStyle(node, style);
```